# Overlay, Search functionality in TVML App

Tags: ios, tvml

We are building a TV application with user login and playing videos with search functionality. So we have designed our home screen with catalog template as in the below picture.

https://i.stack.imgur.com/1BWjl.jpg

Our Pending tasks are 
1. Playing Videos in overlay with  tag.

We are trying to achieve overlay with videofiles in a shelf. An api call result gives a list of videos which has to play in video player. The first item in the array should play in video player and remaining array items should display as overlay in the shelf. On mouse over, video file in overlay, should play in the overlay itself, with the help of  tag, just like thumbnail video play. We tried a lot to play a video in overlay with the  tag. But we couldn't do that.

2. A progress bar to be displayed on the current video which is being
   playing.

We expected video play with progress bar and overlay on video player, but we got the output as in the link. `https://i.stack.imgur.com/gepIo.jpg.`
Progress bar is missing and videos inside the overlay are not playing.

3. Search functionality
   End user can be able to search other users. So we have planned search functionality as a separate link. We have implemented search functionality as a separate template. Its working perfectly, but if i add it in the catalog template as a list item, search template is not loading.

Here is the code for the above application.

https://github.com/TVMLBegnr/TVMLApp

Can any one help me on these tasks. I am not finding TVML experienced people. I can even pay for the tasks.